# Eclipselink Individual Class Cache Configuration

Tags: java, jsp, caching, eclipselink

I added a new boolean field (`myFlag`) to an existing class (`MyClass`).

On the JSP side, I added the following code (`myClassObject` was passed as a request attribute).

```
<span onclick="toggleMyFlag()">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${myClassObject.myFlag}">
            <c:out value="TRUE" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:out value="FALSE" />
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</span>
```

When the `span` is clicked, the flag on the entity is successfully toggled (I can view the change in the database, etc).

However, when the page reloads the TRUE or FALSE outputs have not updated correctly (they remain the same). Refreshing the page doesn't work. Logging out and back in doesn't. And closing the browser doesn't. The only way it seems to fix itself is if I restart my local server.

I tried the following with no luck.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

I also tried the following on my query, again without luck.

```
query.setHint(QueryHints.REFRESH, HintValues.TRUE);
```

Then I found that if I changed the following property (in `persistence.xml`) to be false, the functionality worked.

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="true"/>
```

However, I do not want to turn off all caching like that.

I don't know anything about EclipseLink, so I was wondering if it is possible to turn off caching for just `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your code to recommend which of the followings will work for you for sure but here are the three options you can try depending on your need/code:

```
em.createNamedQuery("MyLocation.findMyLoc").setHint(QueryHints.CACHE_USAGE, CacheUsage.DoNotCheckCache).getResultList().get(0);

@Entity
@Cache(isolation=ISOLATED)
public class Employee {
  ...
}

Or the JPA 2.0 @Cacheable annotation:

@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
public class Employee {
  ...
}
```

[source 1](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache?) ,
[source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809275/disable-caching-in-jpa-eclipselink)

Comment: `@Cache(false)` and `@Cache(isolation=ISOLATED)` both didn't compile. Looks like we are using EclipseLink 2.1.3. The query hint sadly did not work.

Comment: I just tried `@Cache(alwaysRefresh=true)` (which did compile) with no luck.

Comment: what about the NameQuery with "CacheUsage.DoNotCheckCache" ? did you try that too ?

Comment: I did, without. That's what I meant by "the query hint" in my first comment. Although the query is done via `createNativeQuery`. Don't know if that makes a difference.