# Servlet sends old version of entity (JPA)

Tags: java, jpa, servlets, jakarta-ee

When I make a request to my `Servlet`, it checks the database for any updated `Entities` (I am using JPA for that). The updated `Entity` is then fetched and the `Servlet` is supposed to return the entity as a JSON String. **But** I am getting an *old* version of the entity, one that has not been updated yet – although I can see the underlying MySQL database already has the updates. **How is this possible? Am I missing any buffers or caches?**

This is my architecture / the data flow:

```
 ––––––--    timestamp of previous request   ----------–––
| client |–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––>| PullServlet |
 --------        (e.g. 1475056871050)        -------------
                                                   |(injected)
                                                   |
                 --------------------       ---------------
                |   Entity Facade    |<----|    remote     |
                |  implementation    |     | Entity Facade |
                 --------------------       ---------------
                          |
                 @NamedQuery
                 | SELECT m
                 | FROM MyEntity m
                 | WHERE 
                 | m.updated >=:previousRequest
```

Let's say the row in the MySQL database looks like this:

```
 id | updated       | value
 ---+---------------+--------
 12 | 0             | "hi"
```

Then an update is made and the `updated` column logs the time in milliseconds when the update was made:

```
 id | updated       | value
 ---+---------------+--------
 12 | 1475056872002 | "hello"
```

so the query `SELECT ... WHERE 1475056872002 >= 1475056871050` returns the entity because the `updated` column¹ has a value that is greater than the `previousRequest` parameter.

**However** when I log the result of the query, I get something like this

```
id=12, updated=0, value="hi"
```

instead of

```
id=12, updated=1475056872002, value="hello"
```

And the *old* row gets send to my Servlet, which then sends the *old* version as JSON to my client:

```
{
  "id" : 12,
  "updated" : 0,
  "value" : "hi"
}
```

**Question**: is there any cache that I could *"flush"* or anything, to make sure that the selected rows are always up to date?

### Update

So I added some logging and this is the result:

**Facade makes update**

```
UPDATED entity: id=45111, updated=1475067494578, value=100
```

**Client makes request to servlet a few seconds later**

```
Client requested update – fetching entities  // servlet
Facade fetched update: id=45111, updated=1475066854564, value=96  // Facade
servlet received update: id=45111, updated=1475066854564, value=96 // servlet again
```

**Client receives JSON**

```
{
  "id": 45111,     
  "updated": 1475066854564,     
  "value": 96
}
```

### Solution

Thanks to Navneet Arora I found out that the entites where indeed cached and the query used those cached instances instead of retrieving the entites from the database. [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13709765/896249) from another question shows how ignore the cache.

Now my query looks like this:

```
 TypedQuery<Post> query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("MyEntity.getUpdatedSince", MyEntity.class);
 query.setParameter("previousRequest", previousRequest);
 query.setHint(QueryHints.REFRESH, HintValues.TRUE);  //this does the trick
```

And now everything is fine and I get all the updates :)

__________________
¹ the `updated` column and the `previousRequest` parameter are unix timestamps in milliseconds

Comment: Use logging of the exact events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your calling code, you can check if your entity is available in cache or not. If it is available with older value, you can clean it using evict or evictAll method and then try to retrieve values. Following are some sample coding statements for your reference:-

javax.persistence.Cache cache = entityManagerFactory.getCache();

```
  System.out.println("cache.contain should return true if entity exists in cache: "+cache.contains(Order.class, order.Id()));
```

With following code, you can remove entity from cache, if it exists there:

```
            cache.evict(Order.class);
```

Comment: Interesting! Now I get a lot of log entries like: `cache.contain should return true if entity with id 45252 exists in cache: true`.

Comment: Thank you, could you tell me if there is a more "general" way to remove entities from the cache, or stop caching at all? `cache.evict()` sounds quite like a rather "heavy" operation, when having to do it before every request (which is going to be a few times per second)

Comment: To avoid this, you can disable second level cache or can have selective caching setting in persistence.xml file. Actually we should configure L2 caching only in case of frequent read and infrequent modification because having Stale data for updated objects is the drawback of L2 caching.                        Following entry in persistence.xml will disable L2 caching <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>                       In place of NONE, if you put ENABLE_SELECTIVE as value then only those entities which are annotated as @Cacheable(true), will be cached.